# How to display nested list data in tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table, tabulator

I have a search and listing panel in my screen. For the listing page, I am using tabulator because I want to display nested data.

js file code :

```
function onCheckClick() {
var url = "/SomeController/SomeAction/";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "Post",
    success: function (result) {
        var table = new Tabulator("#exampleTable", {
            dataTree: true,
            data: result.data.GroupList,
            dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
            dataTreeElementColumn: "GroupName",
            dataTreeChildField: "childRows",
            columns: [
                { title: "Group Name", field: "GroupName", width: 200, responsive: 0 },
                { title: "%Range", field: "Range", width: 150 },
                { title: "Count Nutrition", field: "FoodCount", width: 150 },
                { title: "Combined", field: "CombinedCount", hozAlign: "center", width: 150 },
            ],
        });
    },
    error: function (reponse) {
    }
});
}
```

The response class file has nested data as follows :
Main Class Group List :

```
public class GroupListViewModel
{
    public List<GroupDetailEntityViewModel> GroupList { get; set; }
    public GroupListViewModel()
    {
        GroupList = new List<GroupDetailEntityViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Nested Class :

```
public class GroupDetailEntityViewModel
{ 
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<FoodDetailViewModel> _children { get; set; }

    public GroupDetailEntityViewModel()
    {
        _children = new List<FoodDetailViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Nested Class FoodDetailViewModel :

```
public class FoodDetailViewModel 
{
    
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Range { get; set; }
    
    public int FoodCount { get; set; } 

    public int CombinedCount { get; set; }
}
```

I want my table to display data like as follows:

[image]

But it is not happening. Only Group name is rendered, nested data is hidden.
I referred to tabulator link and henceforth used `_children` naming convention for my nested list => [Tabulator example](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/tree)

Can Anybody please help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Tabulator is expecting an array of objects on the _children property, you are passing in an object

Comment: I would suggest to use `groupBy` functionality of Tabulator instead nestedData here..

Comment: @OliFolkerd I printed data at the console, it was treating it as an array only.

Comment: @Sachin I will try but can you tell me how does that work in Tabulator?

Comment: The console will show it as an array because it can interperate the List object as such. Tabulator requires the data to be an array, not an itteratable object which is what you have there. if Array.isArray() on the object does not return true then it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because you are passing lists into tabulator not arrays.

While `List` objects are technically iteratable, they are not the same as arrays which is what tabulator requires.

This shows the structure that your data must be presented to tabulator in, in order for it to function. you will notice that the `childRows` property has an array assigned to it:

```js
var tableDataNested = [
    {name:"Oli Bob", location:"United Kingdom", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", childRows:[
        {name:"Mary May", location:"Germany", gender:"female", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
        {name:"Christine Lobowski", location:"France", gender:"female", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
        {name:"Brendon Philips", location:"USA", gender:"male", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", childRows:[
            {name:"Margret Marmajuke", location:"Canada", gender:"female", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
            {name:"Frank Harbours", location:"Russia", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966"},
        ]},
    ]},
    {name:"Jamie Newhart", location:"India", gender:"male", col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985"},
    {name:"Gemma Jane", location:"China", gender:"female", col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", childRows:[
        {name:"Emily Sykes", location:"South Korea", gender:"female", col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
    ]},
    {name:"James Newman", location:"Japan", gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"},
];
```

There is nothing wrong with storing your data the way you are, especially if you need to have other functions to manipulate it in the rest of your app. But in order for tabulator to correctly understand it you will need to map it to the format outlined above before you pass it to Tabulator.

Full details on how to use nested data in Tabulator can be found in the [Data Tree Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/tree)